# Is it possible to determine the html code order of Selenium WebElements

Tags: java, sorting, selenium

Is it possible to find out if one `WebElement` comes before another one in the html code?

More general, is it possible to sort a collection of `WebElement` objects according to their order in the html code? (note: sorting a lot of elements is not actually my intention)

```
/*
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
        <div>first</div>
    </div>
    <div>second</div>
  </body>
</html>
*/
public int compare(WebElement a, WebElement b) {
    return -1; // if a=first, b=second
    return  0; // I'm not really interested in corner cases
    return  1; // if a=second, b=first
}
```

In `XPath` you have the `preceding::` and `following::` axes, but in my case I already have the `WebElement` objects and I want to determine their relative order.

Comment: Why don't you ask your actual question if this is not your intention.

Comment: if what you want to do is have initialized WebElement objects sorted by proximity to the top of the DOM, I don't think that is possible. You would essentially be trying to evaluate shortest node offset from html/ on DOM.

Comment: Well, the first sentence is my actual question, comparing the order of 2 elements. I just thought it would be best to mention the more general case even though I think sorting an entire collection of WebElements is a bad idea. It can be done more efficiently by changing the selector that got you the elements in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I'm curious if others could come up with other solutions. Is there a more direct way to do this without finding like half of the elements on the page?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this and I'm coding it on-the-fly:

```
public WebElement firstInList(WebElement a, WebElement b) {

    WebElement found = null;
    List<WebElement> all = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*");

    for (WebElement test : all) {
        if (test.equals(a)) {
            found = a;
            break;
        } else if (test.equals(b)) {
            found = b;
            break;
        }
    }

    return found;

}
```

Comment: Once you have the list of all elements (in document order) you can just work with `indexOf` instead of the `for`-loop. I think this solution can be improved using the xpath axes I mentioned though. It was something I thought about already but I hoped to discover something not that brute force.

Answer (score 0):

To make it using two differents IWebElements will be a pain - is hard and will take so much time to proccess the information to discovery the html nodes and know where each one is in -> and finaly says who is the first and who is the second one.

My sugestion is using two selectors: cssSelector or Xpath. Both of they are able to mix more than one selecting condition inside itself, and when you try to return a list of IWebElements using `findElements`, it will return based on html order. It means that, the fiers html node will be the first element in the list.

An example (in c#, sorry, i don't know java)

```
public bool IsATheFirstElement(string aXPathSelector, string bXPathSelector)
{
    // Creates a xpath to find both elements: A and B
    var generalXPath = aXPathSelector + " | " + bXPathSelector;

    // Get a list of elements containing A and B, in HTML order
    var ab = _driver.FindElements(By.XPath(generalXPath));

    // Get the A element
    var a = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath(aXPathSelector));

    // Returns a bool value that checks if a is the first element or not
    return ab.First() == a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is rather "brute force".
It looks for all the elements after `a` and sees if `b` is in there.

```
public int compare(WebElement a, WebElement b) {
    if(a.equals(b)){
        return 0;
    }
    List<WebElement> afterA = a.findElements(By.xpath("descendant::* | following::*"));
    if(afterA.contains(b)) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```